# AutoHotKey script for Adobe Acrobat and SketchUp export hotkeys

Tags: adobe, autohotkey, acrobat

I am trying to make Windows+Shift+E (<kbd>⊞</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) hotkey in order to quicken exports in SketchUp and Adobe Acrobat. The AutoHotKey sript is as follows:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#+e::

If WinActive("Acrobat")
    SendInput, {Alt down}
    SendInput, f
    SendInput, t
    SendInput, t

If WinActive("SketchUp")
WinMenuSelectItem, , , File, Export, 2D Graphic...
    SendInput, test.png

Return
```

The SketchUp export hotkey works fine, but I am running into issues with Adobe Acrobat.
The `WinMenuSelectItem, , , File , Export To, Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation` (and `WinMenuSelectItem` in general) does not work on Adobe products. Therefore I have resorted to using `SendInput` for Adobe Acrobat.

If I run the script when SketchUp window is active, it does everything it is supposed to do, but for some reason there are some artifacts from the `If WinActive("Acrobat")` conditional statement part. The "test.png" parts ends up being "tttest.png", "ftttest.png" and etc.

If I run the script when Adobe Acrobat window is active, then it is only able to run once and the Windows (<kbd>⊞</kbd>) key stops working (and some other mayhem), and I have to logout of Windows and log in back in order to resole that.

Could anyone advise me on what is the issue with the `If WinActive("Acrobat")` conditional statemen part of the script?

Answer (score 1):

I have missed something very simple – `{Alt down}` requires `{Alt up}` afterwards. Otherwise the Alt stays pressed, which explains all the mayhem.
Therefore I have replaced the `SendInput, {Alt down}` line with `SendInput, {Alt}` and all is fine with the world.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#+e::

If WinActive("Acrobat")
    SendInput, {Alt}
    SendInput, f
    SendInput, t
    SendInput, t

Return
```